# Weblogic Oracle datasource crashes on server restart

Tags: java, oracle, datasource, weblogic12c

I have configured a Datasource in Weblogic 12.2.1.1. Its a Gridlink datasource for Oracle Load balanced connection (Oracle Dataguard). On weblogic restart it crashes with below error.

If I delete the affected datasource and recreate it works fine.
But if I restart the server again it crashes and the application does not works.

**Error logs**

```
    <Oct 21, 2016, 1:04:51,485 PM BST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "myDS" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:411)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:209)
at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:215)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:302)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Oct 21, 2016, 1:04:55,824 PM BST> <Warning> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162508> <corrupted jar found. file:/home/weblogic/wls1221/user_projects/domains/prod1/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/egate-0.0.3/2d2gk8/war/WEB-INF/lib/standard-1.1.2.jar ,md5sum:cd2e0e43980a00fb6a2742d3afd803b8, lastModified:2014-12-03T10:34:38.000+0000.
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
Oct 21, 2016 1:05:00 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
```